# Weird behavior with ifstreams and rdbuf()

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, ifstream

I've noticed that using `.rdbuf()` on an `ifstream` seems to change it somehow. The following code should show the problem.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    ifstream ifs("Sample.csv");
    cout << "Reading buffer: " << endl;
    cout << ifs.rdbuf(); // Outputs buffer as expected
    cout << "Reading buffer again: " << endl;
    cout << ifs.rdbuf(); // Returns nothing

    return 0;
}
```

The reason this is bothering me is that I'm currently trying to copy the contents of one text file into another using `ofstream ofs; ofs << ifs.rdbuf()`. This works fine but makes reading from `ifs` using `getline(ifs, str)` fail, effectively "breaking" the stream.

Comment: What is the problem? You have already read everything from a file, why do you expect something remain to read?

Comment: you would need to rewind the file because you have consumed the stream with your call: insert `ifs.seekg (0);` between the calls.

Comment: Answer section is below.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I'm still grappling with how streams work!

Comment: @puppydog Don't get discouraged. You'd likely be surprised how many engineers that routinely use C++ have no idea how things like `rdbuf()` actually work. Most don't really *need* to know for their day-to-day use, but once you start diving in it really is an interesting journey. Pat yourself on the back for taking time to swim out a little further from shore.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks man!

Comment: @puppydog  According to the standard (http://eel.is/c++draft/ostream.inserters), `operator<<(basic_streambuf<charT, traits>* sb)` *gets* the characters from sb, which means it advances the seek position. I couldn't find any guarantee that `get` has to preserve the buffer for you to be able to seek back.

Comment: @kfsone: You should be looking at `std::basic_filebuf<CharT, Traits>` as it's a pointer to _that_ that `basic_fstream`'s `rdbuf` returns (and its functions are invoked via virtual dispatch from that `operator<<`). Quite deliberately, and for precisely this reason :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't particularly "weird"; it's the same stream behaviour you see every day. `rdbuf` isn't like `std::stringstream::str()` and it isn't magic — it's a pointer to the buffer, that your `cout` is then reading from just as you would read from the original stream yourself:

```
std::stringstream ss("1");
int x;
if (ss >> x)
   cout << x;
if (ss >> x)   // doesn't work a second time; "1" is already extracted
   cout << x;
```

As your stream is a file stream, you can *seek* it back to the beginning to start from scratch (which will inherently do the same to its underlying buffer).

Comment: Conveying the same behavior using something very likely more familiar to the OP; well done, sir.

Answer (score 3):

`ifs.rdbuf()` returns a pointer to the `ifs`'s corresponding stream buffer object. Sending it to `std::cout` via `<<` overload pulls information from the stream until the end of the buffer is reached (`eof`). Calling `.rdbuf()` again returns "nothing" because there's nothing to read at the end of the buffer. The buffer seek position be explicitly reset to zero by calling `ifs.seekg (0);`.

Comment: Note: Just invoking `ifs.rdbuf()` doesn't advance the seek position. It simply returns a pointer to the stream buffer object associated with the stream. It is what is done with that pointer *afterward* that matters. In this case, you're sending it to `std::cout` via an `operator <<` overload, which will pull from it until `eof`, advancing the seekg position in the stream buffer while doing so. In short, it is sending the result of `rdbuf()` to a sink that is advancing its seek pos. Acquisition of the buffer object by `rdbuf()` is just the first step in that series of events.

Comment: I'd love to upvote this but WhozCraig is right - it's inaccurate at the moment.